# jQuery $.inArray is not working with ASCII characters

Tags: jquery, html

As you can see in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/4ju3h/20/) , I have taken two black coins. If I place a black coin on another black coin then it should show alert that "can't kill your own kind" and place the coins in their previous positions. But as you can see it is not working.

Comment: What alert part are you talking about?

Comment: I mean where do you throw the error "can't kill your own kind"?

Comment: Sorry, its inserted now and I updated the link.

Comment: It's not `$.inArray()` that is failing: when you retrieve the character with `.html()` it is returning the actual character `♜` and then you try to match that single character against the seven-character strings in the array `["&#9820;", "&#9819;"]` (at least, that's what a few `console.log()` statements showed me in FF).

Comment: Yes you are right. I worked around using this `blackCoins[0] = $("#a7").html();` where `#a7` is `id` of the `td` that has that particular black piece. So now it stores the actual character.

Comment: Its working now. I am working on posting the correct Jsfiddle.. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're looking for an HTML Entity Encoded version of your UTF-8 characters. HTML Entity Encoding uses the form `&#XXXX;`, where `XXXX` is the decimal value of the entity (in this case, a UTF-8 character code).

On the JavaScript side, you need to be using the JavaScript form of the entity, which is `\uXXXX`, where `XXXX` is the *hexadecimal* value of the entity. So by converting your decimal values to hex and putting them in the proper form, your search array should be:

```
var blackCoins = ["\u265b", "\u265c"];
```

I'm not sure how the game is supposed to work, but making this change does result in "matches" from `$.inArray()`. So I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, here is the corrected [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/4ju3h/24/)